# Importing xlsx file in rstudio

Tags: r

```
  install.packages("readxl")
  library(readxl)
  read_excel("202007-divvy-tripdata.xlsx")
  colnames(202007-divvy-tripdata.xlsx)
```

showing an error:

> Error in is.data.frame(x) : object 'divvy' not found

Answer (score 2):

Please show your environment. Plus, you have to affect your read_excel to an object:

```
data <- read_excel("202007-divvy-tripdata.xlsx")
colnames(data)
```